# When I reboot or un-sleep my computer, my Cintiq is often not use-able

Tags: 22.04, wacom

I recently switched to 22.04. Switching over was very rocky, but it's running smoothly now.
Except my Cintiq. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

When it isn't working, the cursor simply doesn't follow the stylus.
Sometimes it works to unplug and replug the USB. But only sometimes.

If I type lsusb, it says this:

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3005 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR3011 Bluetooth

Bus 002 Device 006: ID 413c:2110 Dell Computer Corp. Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:1010 Dell Computer Corp. USB 2.0 Hub [MTT]

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c043 Logitech, Inc. MX320/MX400 Laser Mouse

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 005 Device 003: ID 056a:00fa Wacom Co., Ltd DTK-2200 [Cintiq 22HD] tablet

Bus 005 Device 002: ID 056a:00f9 Wacom Co., Ltd DTK-2200 [Cintiq 22HD] hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

It seems to be detected.

Do I need to fix a driver? Where do I get one?
Is there anything else I can try?

I need help!

Comment: What do you mean "cursor simply doesn't follow the stylus"? Do you mean it becomes uncalibrated? Does redoing "Map to Monitor" in "Wacom Tablet" in settings help?

Comment: Moving the stylus doesn't cause the cursor to move at all. I can't calibrate because it doesn't detect any movement.

Comment: Does `sudo udevadm trigger` fix it?

Comment: I managed to test it again.

When I un-slept the computer, lsusb didn't detect the cintiq. I tried unplugging/replugging. That didn't work. I tried sudo udevadm trigger, and that didn't help.

I rebooted, and the cintiq still wasn't working, but lsusb detected it. When I unplugged replugged the usb, the cintiq worked again. I didn't think to try sudo udevadm trigger after the reboot. I'll do that next time.

Sorry for the delayed response - I can only test a solution when it happens to break.

Comment: I did another reboot. When that was done, the cintiq was not working even though `lsusb` detected the usb. I tried `sudo udevadm trigger` and that did not fix the issue. Unplugging/replugging the usb fixed it. Is there anything I can do to streamline things?